# Usage of Reactive Extensions in the "Real World"

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

In order to get familiar with RX, I am looking for examples where RX is used in "real world" projects.

I am interested in both, the .NET version or the JavaScript version.
References to closed source projects would be interesting. Open-source projects would be even more interesting.

It would also be interesting why RX is a good choice for those projects.

I am not looking for tutorials or introductions.

Comment: I answer exactly this question in a series of posts on my blog: http://rehansaeed.co.uk/reactive-extensions-part1-replacing-events/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In less than an hour I was able to add Rx support to [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/), an open source ESB:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/master/src/MassTransit.Reactive

**Update:** As for why it's a good fit, they already had a Subscribe/Unsubscribe mechanism in place. Adding Rx support means that those subscriptions can now be composed together easily. For example, you might have two kinds of messages that share some `CorrelationId`. With Rx you can trivially `Join()` the published messages by that identifier:

```
var someMessages = bus.AsObservable<SomeMessage>();
var otherMessages = bus.AsObservable<AnotherMessage>();

var joined = from s in someMessages
             join o in otherMessages
               on s.CorrelationId equals o.CorrelationId
             select new { s.Something, o.OtherThing };

joined.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

**Also:** Check out https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI for an Rx-powered MVVM framework targeting XAML (WPF, Silverlight, WP), iOS and Android. Very, very cool stuff.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old question, but I've been recently playing with your Reactive extension to MT - any thoughts on how one might get it to "play nice" with unit test schedulers, like the HistoricalScheduler? (very clean implementation, btw!)

Comment: I can't take credit for much of its current state. :) I'd suggest opening an issue on MassTransit to inquire about this (please tag @dahlbyk).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two closed source/commercial examples:

1. Banks are using Rx adapters over their message bus infrastructures.
2. The makers of Nirvana, a web streaming product will be offering an based API in their [next release](http://blog.my-channels.com/2011/03/14/nirvana-net-data-groups-and-rx-clients/#more-768) of the product.